# Algorithm to get indexes in order

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I want to assign indexes, in order, starting from 0, to objects. When an object is destroyed, the index should be freed for another use, eg.:

```
allocate_index() returns 0
allocate_index() returns 1
allocate_index() returns 2
allocate_index() returns 3
allocate_index() returns 4
release_index(1)
release_index(3)
allocate_index() returns 1
allocate_index() returns 3
allocate_index() returns 5
```

This is similar to allocating file descriptor in a unix with open() and releasing with close().
But there is no bound fixed in advance.

Is there an efficient algorithm/data structure for allocating/freeing those indices?

Comment: Use a hashmap ?

Comment: you don't need any special algo. just use 2 structures: tuple with (min index, max index) and list of available/released indexes in range given by tuple. once index is requested, check that list first. if list is empty move max index in tuple.

Comment: @Gijs: a hashmap as a no-nzero probability of collision. This algorithm does not.

Comment: I thought java hashmap was collision save, what kind of language are you working in?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this https://netjs.blogspot.nl/2015/05/how-hashmap-internally-works-in-java.html, if you want to implement it yourself.

Comment: @skyboyer: this looks like O(n) complexity. I was not really asking for the algorithm itself, but more "is this algorithm well-known?". My algorithm currently is: maintain a list containing first available slot & first occupied slot in succession, then add & remove elements from this list.

Comment: @Gijs: I'm working in Elm. Never mind if the algorithm does not exist.

Comment: Deimos, no, it's O(1). you don't need to traverse through list - just to pick it's first element.

Comment: @skyboyer: What about when you delete an item in the middle?

Comment: @skyboyer: the algorithm you propose is equivalent to having a bitmap with 0 for unavailable and 1 for available. What I need is something akin to what is used in memory management: once a memory section is freed, I want the new objects to be allocated to the first free space. This is why a hash map does not work in this context: I need consecutive order!

Comment: @Deimos agree. If you need to pick "first free space" not "any free space" then for sure it will not be O(1). It will be O(log2(N)) since it's complexity for binary search to inject index into list of "indexes became free".

Comment: no, it's not about bitmap with 0/1. you are not required to iterate through all the elements in case there are no indexes have been released

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @Deimos's answer.

Only the released indices need to be stored in a heap data structure as opposed to all available indexes and use an additional variable to keep track of the `currentIndex`. That way if the `next_index` is the consecutive next and not from one of the released index it can be accessed in `O(1)` time as opposed to having the `next_index` pull from an heap of available indices and inserting back again the next available index. Both of which are `O(log N)` operations.

A sample code could look like this

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
class MaintainIndex
{
    private: 
    int currentIndex;
    set<int> releasedIndex;
    public:
    MaintainIndex()
    {
        currentIndex = 1;
    }
    MaintainIndex(int start)
    {
        currentIndex = start;
    }
    int get_index()
    {
        int nextIndex;
        // No released indices available. Return the next consecutive one
        if(releasedIndex.size() == 0) 
        {
            nextIndex = currentIndex;
            currentIndex += 1;
        }
        else //Return the smallest released index
        {
            nextIndex = *releasedIndex.begin();
            releasedIndex.erase(releasedIndex.begin());
        }
        return nextIndex;
    }
    void release_index(int index)
    {
        releasedIndex.insert(index);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll go with a binary heap of available indexes. Thanks for everybody's help + downvoting + closing votes: always a pleasure to ask a question on Stakoverflow!